# How to get html tag data in script?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string:

```
var str = `<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
```

From this string, how can I extract the substring:

```
'Enter a valid email address.'
```

into another variable?

Comment: This should be done using string manipulation or Regex pattern matching. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh No way, don't use a regular expression to try to parse HTML when HTML parsing tools are available

Comment: [*Never* use RegEx to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the text is not trustworthy, the safest (and probably most elegant) option is to use `DOMParser` to turn the text into a document, and then select the `li` in the document:

```js
const str = `<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const a = doc.querySelector('li').textContent;
console.log(a);
```

You might be tempted to use the `innerHTML` of a newly created element:

```js
const str = `<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = str;
const a = container.querySelector('li').textContent;
console.log(a);
```

But this is unsafe, because `error` inline handlers may be executed:

```js
const str = `<ul class="errorlist"><li><img src="" onerror="alert('evil')">Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = str;
const a = container.querySelector('li').textContent;
console.log(a);
```

`DOMParser` does not have the same vulnerability - you can safely use it even when the input string is untrustworthy.

```js
const str = `<ul class="errorlist"><li><img src="" onerror="alert('evil')">Enter a valid email address.</li></ul>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const a = doc.querySelector('li').textContent;
console.log(a);
```